# Bluetooth manager can't find new Bluetooth mouse, but my phone can

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, bluez

Running 18.04.  I had been using a Bluetooth mouse for a couple months, but it stopped working one day and I assumed it had died because I couldn't find it as a Bluetooth device from my phone or a random tablet I tried.

I bought a new cheap Bluetooth mouse, and while my phone finds it immediately my laptop doesn't. It *does* find my fitness watch and a little Bluetooth keyboard I have, but not the mouse.

I have tried doing it through both `blueman-browse` and `blueman-manager`, and neither works (though both eventually die with an "Operation already in progress" exception, which seems to be a thing that they do according to some googling). Also `bt-adapter -d` does the same thing, which makes sense because I think the `blueman` UI tools are just wrappers on top of the `bt-` CLI tools.

I've tried rebooting to no avail. Are there other tools that can diagnose what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, as luck would have it the search I did immediately after posting this hit paydirt. I don't *understand* what needed to be fixed, nor do I have any insight why `bluetoothctl` worked when the `bluez` tools didn't. I just followed the instructions below (taken from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390542) which got them from [here](http://mielke.cc/brltty/doc/Bluetooth.html#for-bluetooth-version-5), thanks whoever you are):

```
# bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 01:23:45:67:89:AB fzidpc73

// choose the controller to work with
[bluetooth]# select 01:23:45:67:89:AB

// show/display the controller details
bluetooth]# show
Controller 01:23:45:67:89:AB
Name: fzidpc73
Alias: fzidpc73-0
Class: 0x000000
Powered: no
Discoverable: no
Pairable: yes
UUID: PnP Information (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Access Profile (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0517
Discovering: no
[bluetooth]# power on
[CHG] Controller 01:23:45:67:89:AB Class: 0x000104
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller 01:23:45:67:89:AB Powered: yes

// scan for bluetooth devices (make sure your mouse is in discovery mode before running this command)
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 01:23:45:67:89:AB Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 34:88:5D:87:C0:A6 Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535
[bluetooth]# scan off
Discovery stopped
[CHG] Controller 01:23:45:67:89:AB Discovering: no

// turn the agent on just incase you need to supply a pin code[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered


// note that the device might not ask you for a pin code

[bluetooth]# pair 34:88:5D:87:C0:A6
Attempting to pair with 34:88:5D:87:C0:A6
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:87:C0:A6 Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 1234
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:87:C0:A6 UUIDs:
00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:87:C0:A6 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:87:C0:A6 Connected: no

// once you have done this use the following two commands to
// complete setup

[bluetooth]# connect 34:88:5D:87:C0:A6
...
[bluetooth]# trust 34:88:5D:87:C0:A6
...
```

If it's not clear the lines starting with `[bluetooth]` are things you type. I'm not sure the responses I got were precisely the same, but they were pretty close. (Well of course the device ID strings were different.)